# How to Get a Vector Layer to add to a QGIS Project

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I used QGIS a little bit a few years ago and used some layers for my city that I had. I have a simple project that I would like to use it for and am having a little problem. I would like to simply get an orthophoto of a parcel that we recently purchased. I found [this thread](http://www.townshipgis.com/resources/problems-and-workarounds/using-the-naip-usgs-1-m-aerials-via-wms-in-qgis).

It is practically what I want to do.  I just want the data for another township in the same state.

I can set up the coordinate system and know the WMS layer I would like to use for the orthos, but, the instructions say to add a vector layer of the specific area I'm interested in.  The example gives Acme Township as an example.  The instructions don't tell me where I can find the layer so I can add it.  In my case I am looking for Mecosta Township, MI.

Can anyone tell me where I might be able to find some sort of shapefile for Mecosta Township. If the layer includes parcels that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a vector layer first to add a WMS layer. Just ignore those instructions. If you post the link to the WMS you are planning to use, we can verify if it works.

Comment: The WMS layer is <http://raster.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/services/Orthoimagery/USGS_EDC_Ortho_NAIP/ImageServer/WMSServer?>

Comment: If I zoom full out I can see the whole US, but, it isn't working when used with the mecosta township political boundaries or hydro shape files.